# New caliper will not close

Tags: brakes, caliper

I'm doing my first ever brake job.  Front brakes on a 2012 Kia Sedona.  New pads, rotors, and calipers.  I'm struggling on the first one because the caliper will not close with the outside pad in.  It's like it's too thick.  The pistons appear to be compressed, but I did C-Clamp them just in case, but no change.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I usually put a flat bar across the piston then put the C clamp on that, for 2 reasons:

1. it tends to keep the piston "square" so it does not lock or jam in the bore which means it does not go back far enough.
2. it makes sure that the piston goes back flush with the caliper so that it will clear the new pads.

Comment: Thanks.  It's definitely not the piston.  Even with just the outer pad, the one that doesn't touch the piston at all, I can't close it.  It's like it's almost there, but it's still about 1/4 inch from being able to screw the bolt in.